# How to reply to a tweet with a text and an image from a json list using tweepy

Tags: python, json, twitter, tweepy

I want every time the bot is mentioned the bot to reply with a certain text and picture. e.g. text is "Winnie the Pooh" and the pic is of winnie the pooh. I've stored the images and texts in a json file. The error I get  is this:

```
api.update_status("@"+tweet.user.screen_name+data[n]["text"]+media_ids=media_list,tweet.id)
                  ^
SyntaxError: expression cannot contain assignment, perhaps you meant "=="?
```

I just can't figure out how to write a reply that include a text and an image. Also the lastseen.txt file is the id of the tweet that has last mentioned the bot.

```
import tweepy
import time
import random
import json

consumer_key=''
consumer_secret=''
key=''
secret=''



auth=tweepy.OAuthHandler(consumer_key, consumer_secret)
auth.set_access_token(key, secret)

api = tweepy.API(auth)

with open('pll/file.json') as json_file:
  data = json.load(json_file)
randomlist = [0,1,2,3,4]
for i in range(0,4):
  n = random.randint(0,4)
  randomlist.append(n)

media_list = list()
response = api.media_upload(data[n]["image"])
media_list.append(response.media_id_string)

FILE_NAME = 'pll/lastseen.txt'
def read_last_seen(FILE_NAME):
    file_read = open(FILE_NAME, 'r')
    last_seen_id = int(file_read.read().strip())
    file_read.close()
    return last_seen_id
def store_last_seen(FILE_NAME, last_seen_id):
    file_write=open(FILE_NAME, 'w')
    file_write.write(str(last_seen_id))
    file_write.close()
    return
def reply():
    tweets=api.mentions_timeline(read_last_seen(FILE_NAME), tweet_mode='extended') 
    for tweet in reversed(tweets):
     
         print(str(tweet.id) + ' _ ' + tweet.full_text)
        
         api.update_status("@"+tweet.user.screen_name+data[n]["text"]+media_ids=media_list,tweet.id)
         store_last_seen(FILE_NAME, tweet.id) 

reply()
```

Comment: The error is coming because you have made a syntax error here "media_ids=media_list"
you can not assign something to an operator or to operands. Also have you tried this link https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/twitter-api/v1/media/upload-media/api-reference/post-media-upload

Comment: @DanishHasan Thanks so much! I looked at the link but I'm decently new to programming so I really don't understand how to fix the problem.